# A minha url não recebe o parametro id no mostra?id=. Por quê?

Tags: php, laravel

**Pergunta:** A minha url não recebe o parâmetro `id` no `mostra?id=.`

**Código:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<?php foreach($produtos as $p): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $p->nome ?></td>
    <td><?= $p->valor ?></td>
    <td><?= $p->descricao ?></td>
    <td><?= $p->quantidade ?></td>
    <td><a href="https://localhost/estoque/public/produtos/mostra?id=<?php 
        $p->id ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Tente trocar `<?php $p->id ?>` por `<?= $p->id ?>`

Comment: Nossa resolveu o problema, valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na parte onde você define o `link`:

```
<a href="https://localhost/estoque/public/produtos/mostra?id=<?php 
        $p->id ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
```

Você não está "escrevendo" o valor do `id`. Então, para que o valor possa aparecer você tem que fazer um `echo`:

```
<?php echo $p->id; ?>
```

Ou você pode utilizar a forma abreviada:

```
<?= $p->id ?>
```